# SQL Logging with Exposed in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

How do you enable logging of sql queries generated by Exposed in Spring Boot?

The following do *not* work:
logging.level.org.jetbrains.exposed.sql: DEBUG
logging.level.org.jetbrains.exposed: DEBUG

Answer (score 14):

logging.level.Exposed: DEBUG

Put it in application.properties.  It will not work without the capital E on Exposed.

Comment: This answer is the first that shows up when you search for "exposed log sql"

So here's the answer if you are using Logback: 
```
    `<logger name="Exposed" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>`

Comment: Do you know how to disable debug logs for Ktor? Exposed always shows full SQL query body in logs, i don't need to see it :\